# Does ActiveRecord automatically lowercase columns named "username"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a database table column named `username` with a unique index. I noticed usernames are lowercased before being sent to the database. Is it ActiveRecord doing this? Can I turn it off? Can I enable it for a differently named column?

Comment: Active Record doesn't downcase strings by default. There is probably some logic in the model that is doing this. Can you post the model code?

Comment: ac @sixty4bit says, activerecord does not, but authentication gems such as Devise does indeed do this

Comment: @trh Aha! App uses Devise. Has to be that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/29142418bade74224d98bbf5bbcadfba181d5db9/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L198

you need to make the username field stay outside of the case_insensitive_keys list inside your devise initializer. that's the "clean" way.

the dirty way would be to "override" the method and specify which are the real case sensitive keys you want in your database.

I would not recommend you to bypass or override it, there is a logic or reason behind case listing those attributes but if your application realy needs it go ahead.